# How to inciude a local html file in a webview in nativescript main-page.js?

Tags: javascript, html, nativescript

**Is it possible to add a local html file in the nativescript webview ? 
If yes How can I do it  using   *javascript* ?**
When I add online page it works , I can add www.google.com in the webview it works .But I want to add a local page but I don't find a way to do this .

Comment: Yes, you can. Simply place html file in your app or assets folder, make sure it's added to bundle then point the file in src attribute - Refer [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/web-view) for more details.

Comment: I have checked the doc I tried the src attribute but it doesn't work it shows me at the screen of the app  the link of the src attribute I complete it with ..

Comment: Pleas share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You need to consider that all NativeScript apps are build by default with **Webpack** and the default ***webpack.config.js*** will take care of certain files (like the ones in a ***fonts*** folder or like all images with *.png and *..jpg extensions). The webpack build will bundle all JavaScript files and in the case of the Angular flavor will also cognitively include the Angular related HTML files. However, the default webpack.config.js won't "know" about your custom HTML file.

The solution is to let Webpack know that it should copy the specific HTML file. This should be done via the **CopyWebpackPlugin** section in ***webpack.config.js*** file.

Example (assuming we have a file called ***test.html*** in the **app** directory)

```
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
        { from: { glob: "test.html" } }, // HERE
        { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
        { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
        { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
    ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
```

For real-life example see [this config](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-js/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L253) where [this HTML file](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-js/blob/master/app/ns-ui-widgets-category/web-view/source-load/test.html) is the one we are targeting.

Comment: Hi dear Thank you for your response .I have tried to find the webpacck.config.js in my project but I don't find it .Can you tell exactly where I can find this file .

Comment: In the `root` folder. If it is missing the do `npm i nativescript-dev-webpack --save-dev` and `./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --configs --deps`

Comment: You should definitely have something like this in webpack.config.js https://github.com/NickIliev/nativescript-ng-cosmos/blob/master/webpack.config.js#L302-L306

Comment: I finally find the section and add an index.html file but It doesn't load it .When I load I get the name of the file index.html printing on my screen .I place the index.html file in the folder app as you showed me in your example .

Comment: Thank you Nick lliev .I add this link for others https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760372/how-to-load-a-local-html-file-into-a-nativescript-webview