# How to load a local html file into a NativeScript webview

Tags: javascript, android, xml, nativescript

**I have modified the webpack.config.js to add a local file called index.html the code below :**

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([
    { from: { glob: "index.html" } },
    { from: { glob: "fonts/**" } },
    { from: { glob: "**/*.jpg" } },
    { from: { glob: "**/*.png" } },
 ], { ignore: [`${relative(appPath, appResourcesFullPath)}/**`] }),
new nsWebpack.GenerateNativeScriptEntryPointsPlugin("bundle"),
```

**This is how I configured my webview in the main-page.xml file the code below:**

```
<WebView row="1" loaded="onWebViewLoaded" id="myWebView" src="index.html"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In NativeScript, by default, the tilde (`~`) marks the app root folder (note the App and not the Project!). So if your file is located in `<project-name>/app/index.html` try setting the path with `~/index.html`.

Comment: Thank you very much dear Nick llliev it works finally