# Make a cross platform application starting from a website

Tags: reactjs, react-native, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I made a website (not yet online), it uses HTML, CSS, Javascript, only. No React or Angular, and I have the following problem :

I'd like to **make a cross-platform application based on** it (for iOS, Android, Windows, Linux and MacOS).
What's the best way to do that ?

**My searches :**

I did few searches, not really satisfactory, because it seems I'll need to re-make my client-website entirely !
I found 2 ways : React Native and NativeScript, like described [here](https://www.davrous.com/2019/01/11/4-ways-to-create-cross-platforms-apps-using-web-technologies/).
Have you some other option ?

If you don't, is it really impossible to keep the code in React ? Like I can see [there](https://medium.com/@davisonpro/an-advanced-guide-on-setting-up-a-react-and-php-web-app-acaedb21ab3a)

I'm a bit confused, and I don't know what I should do to perform what I want.

Thank you for all answers you could give me !

Comment: I was in the same situation a couple of months before, finally, I've ended up with NativeScript. I'd really recommend it cause you can reuse a lot of javascript codes with small changes. The template part is difficult, but not that hard to refactor your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Desktop Development you can try Electron. It's a js library which helps you build cross platform applications by using Node, Chromium and js.
You can also go one step ahead and add react to it.

Applications like VSCode, Skype, Microsoft Teams, Spotify and I think even Slack are made using it.
For Mobile Development, you can go with React Native. In this way you'd make a cross platform mobile dev app too.

The pros are that using these tech stack you can build modern cross platform apps. For a web dev, this is the way to go.

**The cons of Electron**:
It's little heavy on memory, but nothing that would be a bottleneck.

**The cons of React Native**:
Is not suited for apps that require heavy computation and it's bundle size is significantly larger than the native apps

Comment: I will follow your recommendations and I'll first create a mobile app with React Native, and later, a desktop application with Electron.
Also thank you [Peter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2715910/peter) for your recommendation, but I heard much about React Native, that's why I decided to use it.

Thank you both for your answers !

Comment: Sure @Seven
You can use `create-react-app ` or CRA for boiler plate setup. This way you won't waste time in configuring your app. After CRA, add electron package. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to add to this :There is an other option  nw.js for **desktop** app it's like **electron**  using chromium ,node and js.
and for the front-end you can use **angular, react, vue** it is really as you want .This is a link https://nwjs.io/ (**It is cross-platform too** ).

For **mobile development** I think I will recommend you : **NativeScript** (https://play.nativescript.org/?_ga=2.144049845.1620166462.1585302566-1314322155.1583139217) . It is a good option also **cause you can easily add your website(html,css,javascript files ) in your NativeScript webview as your interface** and I think this option won't take you time as making an other one with react-native (even if I know that react-native have his webview too).
So go and have a look to this ::[How to load a local html file into a NativeScript webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60760372/how-to-load-a-local-html-file-into-a-nativescript-webview) .

Then all your work will be the database in sqlite but even for this you have :https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-sqlite and other things to go quickly 
:https://market.nativescript.org/