# Nativescript Composite components

Tags: sass, components, nativescript

> Criei um component com estilo .SCSS porem ele não aplica o estilo.
>   precisar ser especificamente .css o aquivo de estilo?

<sub>(English translation)</sub>
I created a component with .SCSS style but it does not apply the style. need to be specifically .css the style file?

```
{
  ...,
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~1.5.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1"
  },
  ...
}
```

```
.container-search {
  margin: 8;
  padding: 0 5;
  border-radius: 30;     
  background-color: white;

  textField {
    border-width: 1;
    border-color: transparent;
    font-size: 14;
    margin: 0;
    color: #333;
  }
  button {
    width: 35;
    height: 35;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #999;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    font-size: 16;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
}
```

```xml
<StackLayout class="container-search" loaded="onLoaded">
  <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="auto,*,auto" >
    <Button row="0" col="0" id="searchButton" text="&#xf002;" class="las" tap="{{ onSearchSubmit }}" />
    <TextField row="0" col="1" id="searchField" hint="Pesquise.." autocorrect="false" returnKeyType="search" returnPress="{{ onSearchSubmit }}" />
    <Button row="0" col="2" id="searchClear" text="&#xf00d;" class="las" tap="{{ onSearchClear }}" visibility="hidden" />
  </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

```js
import { StackLayout } from "tns-core-modules/ui/layouts/stack-layout/stack-layout";
import { TextField } from "tns-core-modules/ui/text-field/text-field";
import { Button } from "tns-core-modules/ui/button/button";
import { Internationalization } from "~/pages/@shared/utilities/internationalization";
export class SearchBar {

  public static shared: SearchBar;

  private static searchField: TextField;
  private static searchButton: Button;
  private static searchClear: Button;

  public static onLoaded(args: any) {

    const innerComponent = args.object as StackLayout;
    const bindingContext = {...innerComponent.bindingContext};

    SearchBar.searchField = innerComponent.getViewById("searchField") as TextField;
    SearchBar.searchButton = innerComponent.getViewById("searchButton") as Button;
    SearchBar.searchClear = innerComponent.getViewById("searchClear") as Button;

    SearchBar.searchField.on("textChange", SearchBar.onTextChangeST); 

    bindingContext.internationalization = Internationalization.singleton().getData();
    bindingContext.onSearchSubmit = SearchBar.onSearchSubmit;
    bindingContext.onSearchClear = SearchBar.onSearchClear;
    innerComponent.bindingContext = bindingContext;   

    SearchBar.shared = SearchBar;
  }

  public static get onSearchSubmit(): (args: any) => void {
    return SearchBar.onSearchSubmitST;
  }

  public static get onSearchClear(): (args: any) => void {
    return SearchBar.onSearchClearST;
  }

  // Auxiliaries Methods

  private static onTextChangeST(args: any) {

    const text = SearchBar.searchField.text;
    const bindingContext = args.object.page.bindingContext;

    if(text != ""){
      SearchBar.searchClear.visibility = "visible";
    } else {
      SearchBar.searchClear.visibility = "collapse";
      bindingContext.search("");
    }
  }

  private static onSearchSubmitST(args: any) {

    const text = SearchBar.searchField.text;
    const bindingContext = args.object.page.bindingContext;

    if(args.object.id == "searchButton") {

      setTimeout(() => {
        SearchBar.searchField.dismissSoftInput();
      }, 100);
    }    

    const result = bindingContext.search(text);

    if(result == 0) { ()=>{} }
  }

  private static onSearchClearST(args: any) {

    const bindingContext = args.object.page.bindingContext;

    SearchBar.searchField.text = "";
    bindingContext.searchClear();    
  }

}

export const onLoaded = SearchBar.onLoaded;
```

Comment: What you have in your XML? All the file names are same with different extension (XML, JS / TS, SCSS)?

Comment: yes: search-bar.ts, search-bar.scss and search-bar.xml

Comment: Can you show us what you have in your webpack.config.js?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1W7q-WmOMzWTBj1-0q_RZ7n_JssUZoWeN

Comment: That looks good (between you could have pasted it in the OP). I will have to ask for a sample project where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19Ya1ujgMrnocNlej7kGKGrB6mCHkgktD  => TNS: 6.5.0

Comment: The code you have shared is completely different form the OP, still I was able to run it and ensure the XML responds to styling changes on SCSS, both app and page level.

Comment: In the case of pages, the Style correctly applies the problems in the components: In this case the component being tested is SearchBar located at: pages/@shared/components/searchBar.   link sample cleaned: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/files/4414615/sample.zip

Answer (score 1):

Not necessary .css I think You need to include your file in the webpack this is a link to show you an exemple :[How to inciude a local html file in a webview in nativescript main-page.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60624570/how-to-inciude-a-local-html-file-in-a-webview-in-nativescript-main-page-js)

Second option is :Migrate the project to the latest version wiht **tns migrate** if it is not done .

Third option : You need to compile the .scss files with :
**npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader**
I am letting you this link : https://www.tjvantoll.com/2019/08/30/nativescript-sass/

In the case you have not seen this you may try this link 
https://www.tjvantoll.com/2019/08/30/nativescript-sass/

Comment: I think you must try this command   : npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader

Comment: I already did that and I have installed all the dependencies and configured the webpack. In the case of pages, the Style correctly applies the problems in the components. current TNS version: 6.5.0

Comment: I think I told you all I knew .Good luck